# Laravel 5 | File upload - If file exists add number to filename

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, file-upload, request

I have problem with file upload. Now I have something like this (part of Controller):

```
if($request->has('photos')) {
            foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
                $filename = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
                $tmp_name = $filename;

                if ($pos = strrpos($filename, '.')) {
                    $name = substr($filename, 0, $pos);
                    $ext = substr($filename, $pos);
                    
                } else {
                    $name = $filename;
                }

                $uniq_no = 0;
                while (file_exists($filename)) {
                    $tmp_name = $name .'_'. $uniq_no . $ext;
                    $uniq_no++;
                    
                }
                $photo->storeAs('public/photos/',$tmp_name);
                Photo::create([
                    'page_id' => $page->id,
                    'filename' => $tmp_name
                ]);
            }
        }
```

but saves to the database without adding a unique number: filename_0, filename_1 etc. It just saves the value of $tmp_name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should just rather attach time(). Anyway, your while loop condition should check for $tmp_name I believe.

Comment: then how to later display the filename without time in blade?

Comment: Just fetch the substring before last `_`.

Comment: a ok, thanks for solution <3

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
if($request->has('photos')) {
            foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
                $file = $photo->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME).'_'.Str::random(6);
                $extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $fullfilename = $filename .'.'. $extension;
                $photo->storeAs('public/photos/',$fullfilename);
                Photo::create([
                    'page_id' => $page->id,
                    'filename' => $fullfilename
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `Str::random(6)` is not full proof.

Comment: but if I have multiupload of files the "time" will not pass because sometimes I will upload a file with the same name and it will duplicate "time". Then an error pops up.

Comment: `time()` is a function in PHP and it cannot be the same if you use it more than once in your code. There are a lot of ways to achieve uniqueness but this one looks the simplest to deal with.